# AWS CloudFormation: Unable to find existing SG to assign to RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

Created and exported a SG from one template/stack:

```
  Resources
    RDSSecurityGroup:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
        GroupName: "sg-name" 

  Outputs:
    SGRDS:
      Description: security group of rds instances
      Value: !Ref RDSSecurityGroup
      Export:
        Name: SGRDS
```

However, although the export is created when trying to use this SG in an RDS creation using another template (and stack)

```
 Resources
   MYRDS: 
     Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
       Properties: 
       DBSecurityGroups:
        - !ImportValue SGRDS
```

it fails with the following error:

> DBSecurityGroup not found: sg-0983409kdje5999

**Update**: This does not seem to be a problem related to the exported value; assigning the specific SG to my RDS instance for some reason fails either way (I explicitly used the SG name, but I get the above "not found" error with the name instead of the id this time).

For some reason it fails to find the SG.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup`, you need to use the property `VPCSecurityGroups` to specify your imported security group instead of using `DBSecurityGroups`. It fails because the SG you've specified is not a DBSecurityGroup.

There are two ways to set security groups for an RDS instance which is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-vpcsecuritygroups):

1. **DBsecurityGroups** : Security group of type
   `AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup`. This was the older way of securing RDS
   instances.
2. **VPCSecurityGroups**: Security group of type
   `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` which allows you to specify VPC security
   groups to secure your RDS instance.